# Qt auto generate buttons using data from csv

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, button

I am trying to make a simple GUI in qt. The GUI will have clickable button with various names, and depending on mouse clicks them, they will do different thing.

Currently, I am creating the buttons individually, they all have the same properties except name which is different.

I have a text/csv files of the names of buttons needed. Is there a way to loop though the file and create buttons automatically with the button name being the data from the file. ie, if the data in file is, "first" "second" "third". Create 3 buttons with the names, first second and third.

Comment: Yes. They even have the 1 line example code to do it in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have your labels already parsed and stored in a `QStringList labels` or similar:

```
Q_FOREACH(auto label, labels) {
  auto button = new QPushButton(label);
  // configure your button with the common settings here
  some_layout_in_your_ui->addWidget(button);
}
```

Where `some_layout_in_your_ui` is, well, where you want to place the buttons.